# ROS_comm Instal on Raspberry Pi 3 possibly stuck?

Tags: ros, ros-comm, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a new user, so my apologies ahead of time for the noob question. I am currently installing ROS Indigo (ROS_comm) on my Raspberry Pi which has Raspbian (Jessie). The last command I ran was:

$ sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo -j2

as per this set of instructions (step 3.3) [Installing ROS Indigo on the Raspberry Pi](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi)

The terminal displays (typed by hand as mouse/keyboard unresponsive):
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/serialization.h:223.5: note: in in expansion of macro 'ROS_CREATE_SIMPLE_SERIALIZER_ARM' ROS_CREATE_SIMPLE_SERIALIZER_ARM(double);

It has been stuck here for about 4 hours, not sure if this is normal or not. I can't seem to find any info on it. The mouse is hardly responding, so I take this as a bad sign. Any advice is gladly welcomed!

UPDATE: I killed the board and restarted. Ran the command again and it is stuck on the same spot. Green LED on pi is on (as opposed to iterating on/off).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244630/ros_comm-instal-on-raspberry-pi-3-possibly-stuck?/) by [TacoCat_taCocaT](https://answers.ros.org/users/28090/tacocat_tacocat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried increasing your swap? It is explained here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/219575/raspberry-pi2-roscpp-failed-during-indigo-installation/

---

Originally posted by [vahidzj](https://answers.ros.org/users/28397/vahidzj/) with karma: 16 on 2016-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0